# Is it possible for several threads to wait on same object?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a jstack dump that seemingly says that several threads have acquired a lock on the same object. As I understand this is suppose to be impossible but is it?

Here's the code with the crucial wait call inside try block:

```
protected boolean waitMaxWaitingTime(UserInfo aUserInfo) throws EventServiceException {
    final int theMaxWaitingTime = myConfiguration.getMaxWaitingTime();
    if(theMaxWaitingTime <= 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if(aUserInfo.isEventsEmpty()) {
        //monitor for event notification and double checked
        synchronized(aUserInfo) {
            if(aUserInfo.isEventsEmpty()) {
                try {
                    final long theStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    // --- THE CRUCIAL WAIT CALL ---
                    aUserInfo.wait(theMaxWaitingTime);
                    return (System.currentTimeMillis() - theStartTime >= theMaxWaitingTime);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new EventServiceException("Error on waiting max. waiting time!", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here's the jstack dump (selectively):

```
"thread-79" #161 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005d63c000 nid=0x322c in Object.wait() [0x000000007e93c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at de.novanic.eventservice.service.connection.strategy.connector.ConnectionStrategyServerConnectorAdapter.waitMaxWaitingTime(ConnectionStrategyServerConnectorAdapter.java:92)
    - locked <0x000000008b8de758> (a de.novanic.eventservice.service.registry.user.UserInfo)

"thread-77" #159 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005d63a800 nid=0x5384 in Object.wait() [0x000000007e83c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at de.novanic.eventservice.service.connection.strategy.connector.ConnectionStrategyServerConnectorAdapter.waitMaxWaitingTime(ConnectionStrategyServerConnectorAdapter.java:92)
    - locked <0x000000008b8de758> (a de.novanic.eventservice.service.registry.user.UserInfo)

"thread-74" #156 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000006efe6000 nid=0x4828 in Object.wait() [0x000000007e25c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at de.novanic.eventservice.service.connection.strategy.connector.ConnectionStrategyServerConnectorAdapter.waitMaxWaitingTime(ConnectionStrategyServerConnectorAdapter.java:92)
    - locked <0x000000008b8de758> (a de.novanic.eventservice.service.registry.user.UserInfo)
```

As you can see, several different threads (going by names and tid thread IDs, in this thread `thread-79` and `thread-74`) have apparently acquired a lock on the same UserInfo object (0x000000008b8de758) and called wait on it. Am I mistaken or have several threads really acquired lock and called wait on a single object?

Comment: The `if` should be a `while`.

Comment: Except if `aUserInfo.isEventsEmpty()` have ["happens-before"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) constraints. You mustn't use DCL. JVM is free to reorder instructions as long as "happens-before" constraints are filled. In other words, your condition can be true without all assumed operations are processed. Example : you set a boolean to true after setting an attribute. JVM can set boolean before setting attribute and can even allocate attribute, set boolean to true and finally process instance initialization (constructor call).

Comment: @EJP And `return` must be done after the loop ;)

Comment: @denarced `InterruptionException` isn't thrown when `wait` delay expires. On expiration, it just give hand back. `InterruptionException` is thrown when `thread.interrupt()` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dump shows that several threads are waiting on the object monitor (waiting to acquire it), and not that several threads (more than one) have acquired it (at the same time). The former is quite possible and normal. The latter cannot happen.

In other words, yes, several threads have acquired the lock/monitor but that happened serially (one after the other). Once a thread calls wait, it releases the lock and then another thread can acquire it (and then release it again, and so on).

Comment: Moreover, without releasing the monitor lock on `wait`, it will be impossible to `notify` !

Answer (score 6):

> As you can see, several different threads (going by names and tid thread IDs) have apparently acquired a lock on the same `UserInfo` object `(0x000000008b8de758)` and called `wait()` on it.

This is absolutely right. Several threads have called `wait()` on the same object. This sounds counterintuitive at first, because the code is within a `synchronized` block.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) explains this "mystery": the call of `wait()` *releases the ownership of the monitor*, letting other threads enter and start the wait if they wish to

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. **The thread releases ownership of this monitor** and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution. *(emphasis added)*

Answer (score 0):

The threads are blocked on Object's monitor and do not have multiple ownership at any point of time.To assure fairness for acquiring Objects,you can consider using `Lock` and then you may know if any particular thread is taking time to complete and has acquired an Object's monitor for a long period of time